# Can't save file in Ubuntu, user in sudo group

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to create an `odbc.ini` file in the `/etc` folder.

I'm opening a new file in the text-editor and am trying to save, but I always get a permission denied error.

I've added myself to the sudo group, and then I went into manage the group and had to select a checkbox, but I am still getting this error.

How can I set my permissions to be able to create a file in this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually side step any permission issues in linux by acting as the root user.

You could try running the text editor as root:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/odbc.ini
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/odbc.ini
```

Comment: well, that kinda got me there, but really that isn't the ideal way. I have created the file, but now i need to edit it. Editing in VI is far from ideal, so I'm really looking for a way to manage my files using whatever tools I want, not just command line.

Comment: @user: The answer already shows how to use editors other than vi.